# How to show view when clicking Google Maps marker?

Tags: android, view, google-maps-markers, android-geofence

In [this tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-geofencing-google-maps) there is this screenshot:

[image]

I want to show such a view when clicking on the info window of a marker.
I am already handling the onInfoWindowClick:

```
@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
    Log.i(TAG, "oninfowindowclick");        
}
```

However I don't know how to show a view then.
Anyone can give me a simple xml example for a view similar to the one on the screenshot and the few lines to show the view as some kind of dialog?

Thanks for any hint on this!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your `View` and `Map` in  `FrameLayout` and change visibility of your View in `onInfoWindowClick`